# Properly collect data synchronously from an asynchronous source

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to write integration tests using xunit.
my test application is communicating with my testee application through mqtt and for one of my test I want to send a request, collect all received message for an amount of time and then analyse the result to determine if the outcome is what i expect.

I could sucessfuly do it, however, not beeing very familiar with async programing in c#, I have some doubt about the way I do it.
**Can someone tell me if the core idea is right and how can it be improved ?** especially regarding some comments in the code.

First my test code:

```
[Fact]
        public void HandlingMultipleSimultanuousRequests()
        {
            _output.WriteLine("Starting test <HandlingMultipleSimultanuousRequests>");
            bool success = false;
            _com.SendRequestEvent(new RequestScanEvent());
            Task<IList<IScanEvent>> waitTask = WaitAndReturnAll(5);//get all result received the next 5 sec TODO: place before send request, but not running asynchronously (problem for another time)
            IList<IScanEvent> results = waitTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult(); //wait synchronously on the results
            //TODO: test of the validity of what was received
            Assert.True(results.Count > 0);  //TODO: dummy test to replace
        }
```

Then the method I use to wait for the results :

```
 private async Task<IList<IScanEvent>> WaitAndReturnAll(int waitTimeSeconds)
        {
            IList<IScanEvent> scanEvents = new List<IScanEvent>();
            try
            {
                _com.ReceivedScanResult += ReceivedScanEvent;
                _genericScanEventReceived = new TaskCompletionSource<IScanEvent>();

                DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
                while(DateTime.Now < startTime.AddSeconds(waitTimeSeconds))
                { 
                    if (_genericScanEventReceived.Task.Wait(5)) //small error in timespan ms not really a problem
                    {
                        //TODO: should I put a lock here for the receive event...
                        scanEvents.Add(_genericScanEventReceived.Task.Result);
                        _genericScanEventReceived = new TaskCompletionSource<IScanEvent>(); //new event to be ready for next message...
                        //TODO: remove the lock here...
                    }
                }

                _com.ReceivedScanResult -= ReceivedScanEvent; //remove callback before cancellation
                _genericScanEventReceived.SetCanceled();
                _genericScanEventReceived = null;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.LogError(e, "Error during awaiting of request answer, result should still be valid");
                return null;
            }

            return scanEvents;

        }
```

and finally the eventHandler for when I receive a message from the testee:

```
private void ReceivedScanEvent(object? sender, IScanEvent res)
        {
            //TODO: should event queue with a lock, will it work ?
            if (_genericScanEventReceived == null)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("Received scanevent but no test is currently waiting");
                return;
            }
            if (_genericScanEventReceived.Task.IsCompleted)
            {
                //TODO: code smell... this case should not append
                _logger.LogError("A result is already returned, cannot handle the event now..."); 
                return;
            }
            _genericScanEventReceived.SetResult(res);
        }
```

As you can see I use a TaskCompletionSource to collect the data. is it the right tool ?
Also I have some concern about the risk of loosing some messages with my code.

Comment: Why are you trying to run this synchronously? xUnit supports asynchronous tests.

Comment: It might be possible yes, I actually haven't really research it on the xUnit part (I'm a complete beginner with xUnit).
However, I'm using the test project for my application also as a learning tool to test things I might want to use elswhere. my question really is about async programming and not xUnit.

But thank you for pointing that out : it might come handy in the future.